# Import file google drive/import google sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have an apps script script that uploads a file xlsx from my local machine to a folder on the specific drive, but the file is uploading empty, which is incorrect? In this case, how would I also ensure that the data from this file that was uploaded is imported into a specific Google Spreadsheets?

```
function uploadFileToDrive(filePath) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("10ULO2lE0yXaB9aR4nWmw2W3wJK9XjUcX"); // Substitua "folderId" pelo ID da pasta de destino no Google Drive
  var filePath = "/C:/Users/901489108/Downloads/49_baserabig01_1696000100003.xlsx";
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(filePath, "49_baserabig01_1696000100003.xlsx");
  var newFile = folder.createFile(file);
  
  // Obtém o ID do arquivo que efetuou o upload.
  var fileId = newFile.getId();
    
}
```

Comment: There is no createFile method of the Classs DriveApp that takes a file path as a first parameter

Comment: Hi Guilherme, Cooper (as usual) is absolutelly right.
Let think the problem from this perspective: GAS runs "in the cloud" and has no way to access your local file unless the browser (e.g. the gDrive page) post it first to the cloud (gDrive in this case) as when you drag the file to gDrive or uses the New > File upload menu.

Comment: @jpp That's right, I've been deeply searching for ways to do this and it's only possible using gdrive, I managed to upload it correctly, but I can't import it into my specific spreadsheet, do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Remember that there’s more than one way to skin a cat.
My suggestion is to upload your "incoming files" always to the same folder in drive, and write a script to
 explore that folder, 
 get the files on it,
 open the files 
 get the info on each opened file, and merge into your specific spreadsheet
 move the uploaded file to another folder (a folder called done or simply trash it)